# C Converting float to int array

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, int, i2c

I'm trying to convert a 'float' variable to an integer array as I'm going to send it over an I2C bus and I2C only allows me to do 1 byte transactions at a time. I'm thinking of making an integer array of size 4 (1 byte at a index per transaction).

I'm aware this can simply be done if we want to convert 'float' to 'string' using memcpy() but I want to convert my 'float' variable directly to an int array, then send my array to do operations 1 byte at a time. I'd appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's all just arrangements of bits in memory. You need to know what sort of arrangements is expected on the other side of I2C bus.

Comment: I see you've also asked before: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450201/putting-a-variable-of-type-float-on-the-i2c-bus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you really are after, but how about this:

```
// original float value
float value = 42.0f;

// intermediate char buffer to allow memcpy of float's bytes
char charbuf[sizeof float];
memcpy(charbuf, &value, sizeof float);

// the actual int array you want, use for loop to copy the ints
int intarray[sizeof float];
for(unsigned index = 0; index < sizeof float; ++index) {
    intarray[index] = charbuf[index];
}
```

In case you are actually fine with an integer array (`char` is an integer), and don't require the use of the exact `int[]` type, then you can just skip that last part of above code.